# How can I override an Objective-C Cordova class without hacking the source?

Tags: objective-c, cordova, cordova-2.0.0

I am new to Objective-C so sorry if this is inanely simple. I am trying to alter the **PhoneGap Capture Feature** to add some text on the audio and video capture screens that pop up when you call `capture.captureAudio` and `capture.captureVideo`.

I have found I can alter the Cordova source and change the loadView method of the  `CDVAudioRecorderViewController` to add a text field and alter the appearance. Likewise I imagine I should be able to do the same with the `CDVImagePicker` class.

I know hacking the source of a library is a bad idea so I am wondering what are the other simple ways I could go about doing this?

Is there a sneaky simple way to substitute an inherited class in Objective-C? Perhaps by changing a factory (`init`) method somehow? If so, how do I set this up within my own codebase so that it will use my changes ahead of the original code?

If not does that mean I have to resort to creating a plugin that overrides `CDVCapture` find every method that mentions the classes I want to sub out and replace them with my new class that inherits form `CDVAudioRecorderViewController` just to override a single method on `CDVAudioRecorderViewController`?

Comment: google for objc method swizzle

Comment: Probably subclass it.  You have the headers and therein are all the methods that are accessible to you.  Create a new class... then copy the method declaration line out of the header, paste it in and write new code.  Then at the end call the original using [super...].

Comment: Thanks @xlc I just had a google and found class posing and method swizzling. Feels a little naughty from a design perspective but honestly I think it is the best way to minimally separate the code I need to change. Its only for a prototype so if I need to build the whole thing out as a plugin I can do that later.